# How to cut a certain range of y axis in pointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I created a seaborn pointplot with the following script :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plot = sns.pointplot(ax=ax, data=Dataframe, x="Month", y="CovDist", hue='Tag')
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure is this:

[image]

The problem is that the blue line corresponding to VC is completely out of scale compared to the other elements, so the patterns are impossible to observe.
Basically, I would like to cut my Y-axis to 5000 to reproduce only the upper part (more thatn 10 000) of the blue line values, keeping the lower part with the rest of the lines zoomed in.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html

Comment: Maybe work with a logarithmic y-axis.

Comment: Don’t do `plot =` as you already have `ax` as the alias. `ax.set(yscale="log")`

Comment: There are many broken axis examples [matplotlib split the y axis site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+split+the+y+axis+site%3Astackoverflow.com&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS678US683&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)